# Tabbed Docking interface like photoshop

Tags: delphi, tabs, panels, docking

I was wondering which component to use to get the same tabbed docking that photoshop using, in photoshop you can dock panels as tabs and you can reorder them by dragging the tab or you can dock them together under each other,

I have tried to mimic same results with the jvcl and lmd docking components but apperantly they are not same with the system of photoshop using,

can you let me know which component to use to get the same result or anyone has any example for me to study and work on

[image]

Comment: There is no specific library in delphi which photoshop uses. First of all, Photoshop isn't written in Delphi. Second of all, Photoshop has its own system and UI code. There wouldn't be components for it anyway. There are many third-party libraries which can mimic it, but that's off-topic here.

Comment: I would say what's on the picture should do any docking framework (including the default Delphi docking support). See e.g. this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2601068/8041231.

Comment: @JerryDodge i was guessing photoshop isnt written in delphi but what i try to achieve here is that how can i achieve the same or similar docking system, i think there must be a third party component for delphi that allows me to do the same like in photoshop, i tried using delphi docking system but it is terrible i tried to use jvcl and lmd docking components but they are not same

Comment: @Victoria i tried delphi's built in docking system and jvcl and lmd they are not even close the smoothness of photoshop like docking system

Comment: Off topic to ask for library recommendations here. Ask elsewhere. For instance delphi developers group on Google+.

Answer (score 1):

LMD Docking is ubdoubtedly the closest thing you will come across for delphi. We use it in FinalBuilder and you can definitely drag docked tabs around like in in photoshop. [FinalBuilder - an example implementation of LMD Docking](https://www.finalbuilder.com)

Comment: I tried lmd docking component (sure it is much more better than delphi's built in docking system) but still it seems far away than the quality of the photoshop docking system, panels moving slow and no animations on drag tabs to change order, i cheched every option and parameter in the lmd docking manager but i couldnt success to get close what i want, maybe i am missing something? Is there any other options to make lmd act like close to photoshop like docking? Is there anyway you can provide me an example?